# find words comprised of repeated characters in python

Tags: python, regex, repeat

Disclaimer: I found quite a lot of similar questions, but not the specific one. Once someone answered, I will delete it.

I need to find all masked words such as:

> AAAAA likes apples, but BBBBB likes bananas. Their phone numbers are 
>   ffffr and ggggh.

The pattern is at least three times of a repeated character.

When I use:

```
import re

p = re.compile(r'[a-z]{3,}, re.IGNORECASE)
m = p.findall('AAAAA likes apples, but BBBBB likes bananas. Their phone numbers are ffffr and ggggh.')
```

I get simply all words (which contain more than 3 characters).

Ideally, I should get only:

```
m = ['AAAAA', 'BBBBB', 'ffffr', 'ggggh']
```

How should I change the rage rules to capture only those?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Your current regex just checks for three or more `[a-z]` but not for repeated. For checking if a letter is repeated, you'd need to [capture](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and [backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) it later. Using your `re.IGNORECASE`

```
\b\w*?([a-z])\1\1\w*\b
```

- `\b` matches a [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)
- `\w` matches a [word character](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html)
- `([a-z])` captures an alphabetic character to `\1`
- `\1` is a backreference to what's captured by the first group

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/zjKIGV/1)

This would match at least 3 repeated `[a-z]` surrounded by any amount of `\w` word characters.

Comment: Thanks! I thought there should be a lot simpler solution, but definitely need to educate myself better on regex.

Comment: @ArnoldKlein Welcome! Had time to add a bit more explanation. Glad it helped =)

Answer (score 1):

Here, if we wish to capture a word, we would be using a word boundary with back-referencing with an expression similar to:

```
\b([a-z])\1\1\1.+?\b
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HT97ko/1/)

#### Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"\b([a-z])\1\1\1.+?\b"

test_str = "AAAAA likes apples, but BBBBB likes bananas. Their phone numbers are ffffr and ggggh."

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression, but I suggest using other way, namely:

```
txt = 'AAAAA likes apples, but BBBBB likes bananas. Their phone numbers are ffffr and ggggh.'
words = txt.split(' ')
found = [i for i in words if len(set(i[:3].lower()))==1]
print(found) # ['AAAAA', 'BBBBB', 'ffffr', 'ggggh.']
```

Note that now `found` is not exactly same as your desired output, because of `.` in last element, but we could easily remove any trailing punctuation following way:

```
import string
clear_found = [i.rstrip(string.punctuation) for i in found]
print(clear_found) # ['AAAAA', 'BBBBB', 'ffffr', 'ggggh']
```

Explanation of my method: I get 3 first characters of word, turn all of them lowercase, then use `set` to check if there is only one letter (character). Alternatively you could use `.upper` method of `str`. Feel free to use regex-based solution if you consider it better suited for your use-case, but please keep in mind that there is possibility of non-regex solution for certain problems.

Comment: Interesting! I will try.